# Does TypeScript require node.js to run?

Tags: node.js, typescript

Installing TypeScript requires node.js. And I assume that TypeScript uses Node.js to compile the .ts to a .js file.

My question is, does that created .js file require node.js? The ones I've seen so far appear not to. I don't want to load node.js into my html pages if it's not used.

thanks - dave

Comment: No, it does not. You seem to have misconceptions about Node, and how TypeScript and JavaScript are run. Once TypeScript is compiled (through the tsc (TypeScript compiler)) it gets converted to normal JavaScript that can then run as if it were normal JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, TypeScript just emits regular JavaScript.

If you use the "external modules" feature of the language (`import x = require('foo');`) you'll need to compile for either CommonJS (node) or AMD (require.js) and have those available, but that's opt-in.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, can you explain?

Comment: @AlexDresko The `import x = require('foo');` thing. TypeScript 1 will include proper ES6 import/export syntax :)

Comment: There are no planned changes to import/export syntax for 1.0.

Comment: I love it when the guy who works on TypeScript is like, "Say WHAT!?!?!?!"

Comment: @AlexDresko LOL! I know who Ryan is :) TypeScript, is supposed to fix this at some point I remember it from a keynote I attended and from the road map. Apparently it's 1.x and not 1.0 though.